# How to build and debug Delphi using VSCODE?

Tags: visual-studio-code, delphi

Is there any extension that helps me to build and debug Delphi projects using VSCODE?

I looked for and discovered some extensions we can use to run VCL form in VSCODE, but I`ve not been getting how to build, let alone debug.

Comment: https://www.omnipascal.com/

Comment: I am quite certain that debugging is not possible.